# jenkins injects global environment variables into the container, causing environment variable conflicts when python is executed in the container

Tags: python

This is my jenkinfile

```
stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    label '1.63slave'
                    image 'linux-c4702-image'
                    args  '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            when {
                expression {params.build == 'yes'}
                beforeAgent true
            }
            steps {
                script{
                    sh """#!/bin/bash
                            
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE} && mv -f /home/nanopb-0.3.6-linux-x86.tar.gz ${env.WORKSPACE}/adsp_proc/ssc/tools
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE}/adsp_proc/ssc/tools && tar -zxvf nanopb-0.3.6-linux-x86.tar.gz
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE}/adsp_proc
                            pwd
                            python ssc/build/config_nanopb_dependency.py -f nanopb-0.3.6-linux-x86
                            python ./build/build.py -c sm6150 -o all -f aDSP
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE} && source set_env.sh
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE} && sh buildNonhlos.sh all
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE} && bitbake qti-multimedia-image
                            cd ${env.WORKSPACE} && sh buildNonhlos.sh nonhlos
                        """
                }
            
            }
        }
```

This is my python wrong

```
  #Check that boot_images folder exists, there are dependencies on this
  if BOOT_IMAGES_DIR not in os.environ["WORKSPACE"]:
      raise NameError("ERROR: buildex::setup_environment: " + \
      "Build root folder 'boot_images' is missing. Please ensure this folder exist.")
```

Because jenkins global environment variables conflict with python
[jenkins gloval env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA9KK.png)
The Jenkins log shows WORKSPACE as in jenkins ${env.WORKSPACE},However, the WORKSPACE required in python is ${env.WORKSPACE}/boot_images,I have no problem trying to run python without Jenkins

use jenkins environment {} and withEnv to change is useless

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend an environment variable definition in front of a commands:

```
WORKSPACE="${env.WORKSPACE}/boot_images" python <script.py> <arguments...>
```

will set that environment variable just for that command.